# How to convert UTC date to local date object?

Tags: javascript, datetime, momentjs, javascript-objects

I dont know why, but I have tried all the solutions available around the internet but still couldnt succeed. Event MomentJs couldnt help.
So, I have a date string, "2017-06-05T15:00:00Z", it is coming from rest api. 
I even tried with moment js but doenst help. 
**Note I want date object to be returned as the library expects date object not local string.**
So, far I tried:

```
var d = new Date('2017-06-05T15:00:00Z')
console.log(d.getHours())
```

The above code prints 17 rather than 15! So, what is it I am doing wrong? As the library also while doing its own thing gets 1700 hours as in calendar it shows 1700 hrs rather than 1500 hrs.

Comment: Remove the Z...

Comment: @Jonasw sorry, its coming from rest api, unless you want me to process the string, but is that the only way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use the [`getTimezoneOffsetMethod`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTimezoneOffset)

```
var d = new Date('2017-06-05T15:00:00Z')
d.setHours(d.getHours() + (d.getTimezoneOffset() / 60))
console.log(d.getHours()) // 15
```

Comment: Note that this won't work for timezones with offsets that are not a multiple of hours, such as UTC+6:30

Answer (score 0):

```
'2017-06-05T15:00:00Z'
```

The *Z* means *Zulu* (UTC +0:00). So this timestring specifies that it is no *local* but rather a *global* time. The Date Object is local, so:

```
new Date('2017-06-05T15:00:00Z');
```

Gives back the local Date, when it was 15 a clock at Zulu. So youre currently at the timezone UTC+2:00.

So all you need to get the timestring to become local is to remove the "Z":

```
new Date('2017-06-05T15:00:00Z'.replace("Z",""));
```

or you remove the timezone offset, see other answer...